# Data model for complex tree (multiple children and multiple parents)

Tags: javascript, performance, tree

I'd like to have a discussion on the data model (mostly) for **a tree with nodes having multiple children and multiple parents**.

I already have a working algorithm, but I'm looking for improvements.
The things to keep in mind are the feasibility of the algorithm and the performances. Here is the data I'm using currently:

I have an **Array** that contains an **Array** for each level. Every **level Array** contains at each index a node (which is an object containing required data). So it looks as follow:

```
var treeData = [
  [{
    level: 0,
    index: 0,
    label: 'root',
    children: [{
      level: 1,
      index: 0
    }, {
      level: 1,
      index: 1
    }]
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    index: 0,
    label: 'node1',
    parents: [{
      level: 0,
      index: 0
    }],
    children: [{
      level: 2,
      index: 0
    }]
  }, {
    level: 1,
    index: 1,
    label: 'node2',
    parents: [{
      level: 0,
      index: 0
    }],
    children: [{
      level: 2,
      index: 0
    }]
  }],
  [{
    level: 2,
    index: 0,
    label: 'node3',
    parents: [{
      level: 1,
      index: 0
    }, {
      level: 1,
      index: 1
    }],
  }]
];
```

I listed the key points of performance that I have in mind bellow. I'll explain basically how it works on my algorithm, the current performances of the data model I use (form my algorithm point of view) and mark the performance of every key point from my point of view.

*Note: Memory should not be a problem.*

### Access to a node (performance: 5/5)

**Currently:** Instant =)

Because of the access via index, there is no search to access a node.

ie: Only requires `node[level][index]`.

---

### Calculation of a node x and y position (performance: 4/5)

*Note: Requires that a node knows its previous sibling, its parents and children.*

**Currently:** correct because of the instant node access

A node do not have information about its previous sibling in its data. So currently I need to use a "trick" and there is a prerequisite of every node in a level being in the correct order ! Meaning I can use the following code from node at level 1 and index 1 to access its previous sibling which is level 1 and index 0: `node[node.level][node.index - 1]`.

I'll mark it 4/5 because I'd have loved the nodes to automatically adapt their position to their neighbor. So That when I insert, I don't have to recalculate, the nodes will adapt themselves. But I didn't come up with a solution to this yet.

---

### Insertion of a node (performance: 0/5)

*Note: Not yet perfectly available, mostly because there is no tree balancing algorithm.*

**Currently:** A shame, hard to implement, and possibly very long.

The insertion is the weakness of the data model I'm using. I think it's the worst way to handle an insertion. And that's what makes me think I need to change the data model, because depending on the operation, the performances are very unbalanced.

Here is what I need to do to insert a node:

- Insert (not push) the node at its level (meaning I need to search its correct position into the level)
- And recalculate ALL indices.

Yes, recalculate **ALL** indices. The reason being that every node keeps its index and the indices of each of its parents and children. Also after this step I need to recalculate all positions. Used on big trees, it could take lots of time.

---

### Deletion of a node (performance: 0/5)

*Note: Not yet implemented*

**Currently:** I haven't implemented it yet, but I guess it'd work the same way as the insertion. A node removed requires to recalculate all indices at the level and spread it to every affected parents and children.

---

### Questions

- What would be the most balanced data model ?
- Do you find any algorithm improvements ?

Here is my implementation: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46fp0u38/)

I'm using Javascript, SVG and VueJS.

*Note: There are some issues on the insertion and links curves.*

*Note: I can detail more the algorithm if you feel it's needed.*

```js
/*** COMPONENTS ***/
var nodeTemplate = {
  template: '#node-template',
  props: ['node']
};

var linkTemplate = {
  template: '#link-template',
  props: ['link'],
  methods: {
    getPath
  }
};

/** DATA + SERVICE **/

var data = [
      [{
        level: 0,
        index: 0,
        label: 'root',
        children: [{
          level: 1,
          index: 0
        }, {
          level: 1,
          index: 1
        }]
      }],
      [{
        level: 1,
        index: 0,
        label: 'node1',
        parents: [{
          level: 0,
          index: 0
        }],
        children: [{
          level: 2,
          index: 0
        }]
      }, {
        level: 1,
        index: 1,
        label: 'node2',
        parents: [{
          level: 0,
          index: 0
        }],
        children: [{
          level: 2,
          index: 0
        }]
      }],
      [{
        level: 2,
        index: 0,
        label: 'node3',
        parents: [{
          level: 1,
          index: 0
        }, {
          level: 1,
          index: 1
        }],
      }]
    ];

var treeService = {
  data: data,
  verticalSpacing: 50,
  componentMargin: 25,
  componentHeight: 50,
  componentWidth: 100,
  svgWidth: 0,
  svgHeight: 0,
  svgPadding: {
    top: 50,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  }
};

/***** ALGO DRAW TREE *****/

/** START TOOLS FUNCTIONS **/
function hasParents(node) {
  return node.parents && node.parents.length > 0;
}

function hasChildren(node) {
  return node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}

function firstParent(node) {
  var firstParent = node;
  var savedX = treeService.svgWidth + treeService.svgPadding.left + treeService.svgPadding.right;

  if (hasParents(node)) {
    node.parents.forEach(function(parent) {
      if (treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index].x < savedX) {
        savedX = treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index].x;
        firstParent = treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index];
      }
    });
  }
  return firstParent;
}

function lastParent(node) {
  var lastParent = node;
  var savedX = 0;

  if (hasParents(node)) {
    node.parents.forEach(function(parent) {
      if (treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index].x > savedX) {
        savedX = treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index].x;
        lastParent = treeService.data[parent.level][parent.index];
      }
    });
  }
  return lastParent;
}

function firstChild(node) {
  var firstChild = node;
  var savedX = treeService.svgWidth + treeService.svgPadding.left + treeService.svgPadding.right;

  if (hasChildren(node)) {
    node.children.forEach(function(child) {
      if (treeService.data[child.level][child.index].x < savedX) {
        savedX = treeService.data[child.level][child.index].x;
        firstChild = treeService.data[child.level][child.index];
      }
    });
  }
  return firstChild;
}

function lastChild(node) {
  var lastChild = node;
  var savedX = 0;

  if (hasChildren(node)) {
    node.children.forEach(function(child) {
      if (treeService.data[child.level][child.index].x > savedX) {
        savedX = treeService.data[child.level][child.index].x;
        lastChild = treeService.data[child.level][child.index];
      }
    });
  }
  return lastChild;
}

function isSameNode(node1, node2) {
  return node1.level == node2.level && node1.index == node2.index;
}

function areSiblings(node1, node2) {
 var siblings = false;
  
 node1.parents.forEach(function(parent1) {
    node2.parents.forEach(function(parent2) {
   if (parent1.level == parent2.level && parent1.index == parent2.index) {
       siblings = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (siblings) {
     return;
    }
  });
  return siblings;
}

function getParentPosition(node) {
 var index = 0;
  
 for (var i = 1; node.index - i >= 0; ++i) {
   if (areSiblings(node, treeService.data[node.level][node.index - i])) {
     ++index;
    }
  }

  return index;
}

function hasPreviousSibling(node) {
  // if node is not first child of its first parent
  return getParentPosition(node) != 0;
}

/** END TOOLS FUNCTIONS **/

function calculateWeight(level, index) {
  var node = treeService.data[level][index];

  node.weight = 0;
  if (hasChildren(node)) {
    node.children.forEach(function(child) {
      node.weight += calculateWeight(child.level, child.index);
    });
  } else {
    node.weight = 1;
  }
  return node.weight;
}

function calculateSvgSize() {
  treeService.svgWidth = (treeService.data[0][0].weight * (treeService.componentWidth + treeService.componentMargin)) + treeService.svgPadding.left + treeService.svgPadding.right;
  treeService.svgHeight = (treeService.data.length * treeService.componentHeight) + ((treeService.data.length - 1) * treeService.verticalSpacing) + treeService.svgPadding.top + treeService.svgPadding.bottom;
}

function calculatePositionX(tree, node) {
  var result = 0;

  // root
  if (!node.parents || node.parents.length == 0) {
    result = (treeService.svgWidth / 2);
  } else {
    var firstParent = tree[node.parents[0].level][node.parents[0].index];
    var lastParent = tree[node.parents[node.parents.length - 1].level][node.parents[node.parents.length - 1].index];
    var previousSibling = tree[node.level][node.index - 1];
    var halfComponentSize = (treeService.componentWidth + treeService.componentMargin) / 2;

    var centerX = (firstParent.x + lastParent.x) / 2;
    var halfSiblingSize = firstParent.weight * halfComponentSize;
    var halfOwnSpace = node.weight * halfComponentSize;

    if (hasPreviousSibling(node)) {
      var previousEnd = previousSibling.x + (previousSibling.weight * halfComponentSize);
    }

    result = halfOwnSpace;

    if (hasPreviousSibling(node)) {
      result += previousEnd;
    } else {
      result += centerX - halfSiblingSize;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function placeNodes(tree) {
  treeService.data.forEach(function(level, levelIndex) {
    level.forEach(function(node, nodeIndex) {
      node.x = calculatePositionX(tree, node) + treeService.svgPadding.left;
      node.y = ((treeService.verticalSpacing + treeService.componentHeight) * levelIndex) + (treeService.componentHeight / 2) + treeService.svgPadding.top;
    });
  });
}

function rePlaceRoot() {
  var halfComponentSize = (treeService.componentWidth + treeService.componentMargin) / 2;

  var centerX = (treeService.svgWidth / 2);
  var firstChildHalfSpace = treeService.data[1][0].weight * halfComponentSize;
  var lastChildHalfSpace = treeService.data[1][treeService.data[1].length - 1].weight * halfComponentSize;

  treeService.data[0][0].x = ((treeService.svgWidth - firstChildHalfSpace - lastChildHalfSpace) / 2) + firstChildHalfSpace;
}

function calculateFullTree() {
  calculateWeight(0, 0);
  calculateSvgSize();
  placeNodes(treeService.data);
  rePlaceRoot();
}

calculateFullTree();

/** CREATE VUE **/

function getAllNodes(tree) {
  var nodes = [];

  tree.forEach(function(level) {
    level.forEach(function(node) {
      nodes.push(node);
    });
  });
  return nodes;
}

function getAllLinks(tree) {
  var links = [];

  tree.forEach(function(level) {
    level.forEach(function(node) {
      if (hasChildren(node)) {
        node.children.forEach(function(child) {
          var childNode = tree[child.level][child.index];

          links.push({
           id: 'link' + node.level + node.index + childNode.level + childNode.index,
            start: {
              x: node.x,
              y: node.y
            },
            end: {
              x: childNode.x,
              y: childNode.y
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
  return links;
}

function getPath(link) {
  var moveTo = 'M' + link.start.x + ',' + link.start.y;
  var verticalFirst = 'V' + (link.end.y - (treeService.verticalSpacing / 2) - (treeService.componentHeight / 2));
  var horizontal = 'H' + link.end.x;
  var verticalSecond = 'V' + link.end.y;

  return moveTo + verticalFirst + horizontal + verticalSecond;
}

/** START RANDOM **/

function reCalculateIndices(newNodeLevel, newNodeIndex) {
  treeService.data.forEach(function(level) {
    level.forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.level == newNodeLevel && node.index >= newNodeIndex) {
        ++node.index;
      }
      if (hasParents(node)) {
        node.parents.forEach(function(parent) {
          if (parent.level == newNodeLevel && parent.index >= newNodeIndex) {
            ++parent.index;
          }
        });
      }
      if (hasChildren(node)) {
        node.children.forEach(function(child) {
          if (child.level == newNodeLevel && child.index >= newNodeIndex) {
            ++child.index;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

var index = 0;

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function insertRandomNode() {
 var newNodeLevel = random(1, treeService.data.length);
  var newNodeIndex = 0;
  
  if (treeService.data[newNodeLevel]) {
    newNodeIndex = random(0, treeService.data[newNodeLevel].length);
  }

  reCalculateIndices(newNodeLevel, newNodeIndex);

  // Add a parent to the newNode
  var parents = [];
  var parentLevel = newNodeLevel - 1;
  var parentIndex = random(0, treeService.data[parentLevel].length - 1);

  parents.push({
    level: parentLevel,
    index: parentIndex
  });
  if (!treeService.data[parentLevel][parentIndex].children) {
    treeService.data[parentLevel][parentIndex].children = [];
  }
  
  treeService.data[parentLevel][parentIndex].children.push({
    level: newNodeLevel,
    index: newNodeIndex
  });

  // Add a child to the newNode
  var children = [];
  if (newNodeLevel < treeService.data.length - 1) {
    var childLevel = random(newNodeLevel + 1, treeService.data.length - 1);
    var childIndex = random(0, treeService.data[childLevel].length - 1);

  children.push({
      level: childLevel,
      index: childIndex
    });
    treeService.data[childLevel][childIndex].parents.push({
      level: newNodeLevel,
      index: newNodeIndex
    });
  }

  var newNode = {
    level: newNodeLevel,
    index: newNodeIndex,
    label: 'random' + index++,
    parents: parents,
    children: children,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    weight: 0
  };

  if (!treeService.data[newNodeLevel]) {
    treeService.data.$set(newNodeLevel, []);
  }
  treeService.data[newNodeLevel].splice(newNodeIndex, 0, newNode);
  calculateFullTree();
}

/** END RANDOM **/

new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    service: treeService
  },
  methods: {
    getAllNodes,
    getAllLinks,
    insertRandomNode
  },
  components: {
    'node-template': nodeTemplate,
    'link-template': linkTemplate
  }
});
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.node rect {
  fill: #DFF3FF;
  stroke: #49ACEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="x-template" id="node-template">
  <g class="node" transform="translate({{node.x - 50}}, {{node.y - 25}})">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="100"></rect>
    <text x="5" y="15">{{node.label}}</text>
    <text x="5" y="30">treePos: [{{node.level}}][{{node.index}}]</text>
    <text x="5" y="45">weight: {{node.weight}}</text>
  </g>
</script>

<script type="x-template" id="link-template">
  <path id="{{link.id}}" class="link" v-bind:d="getPath(link)">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <button v-on:click="insertRandomNode()">Insert random</button>
  <svg v-bind:width="service.svgWidth" v-bind:height="service.svgHeight + 10">
    <link-template v-for="link in getAllLinks(service.data)" v-bind:link="link"></link-template>
    <node-template v-for="node in getAllNodes(service.data)" v-bind:node="node"></node-template>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, So if I understand, a node at level `l` can only have parents at level `l-1` and can only have childs at level `l+1`, right ?

Comment: No. That's how my insertion work, because it is incomplete. But the link algorithm can handle more: https://jsfiddle.net/46fp0u38/1/ So a node can have children at level `l+n` and parents at level `l-n`. Although I don't think it should be allowed for a node to be at level 3, for example, and have its only parent at level 1. It should have **at least one parent** at the level `l-1`

Comment: Ok, if so, does the attribut `level` actually have a meaning or it's just used as index in addition to `index` ?

Comment: The `level` is an index that goes from top of the tree (`0`) to the end of the tree (`treeData.length - 1`). At this point, you have located an array of nodes (the nodes of the level index). At this level you have `treeData[level].length - 1` nodes.

Comment: So you are really talking about a graph structure and not a tree?

Comment: You can call it a graph, but the layout looks a lot more like a tree. And it has to be taken in account to calculate the positions.